# What's the difference between 値段 and 価格

Tags: word-choice, words

They're both "price", but I don't see the difference. Even the Kanji appear to suggest similar meanings. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"値段" (mixed *kun-on* compound) is a rather colloquial word, used in most part of our daily life. In most cases, 値段 refers to "how much we/you have to pay" in individual transactions, from the viewpoint of those who buy or sell the item.

> 慌てて買う前に、値段をよく確かめよう。
>
> あのお店でレアなグッズを見つけたけど、値段が高すぎて買えなかったよ。

Using 価格 in casual conversations like these is not incorrect, but sounds a bit unnatural to me.

On the other hand, the usage of "価格" is that of typical 漢語. In serious written articles or business conversations, we mainly use 価格:

> 原油産出量の増加に伴い、ここ数年、石油の価格は緩徐な下落傾向にある。
>
> 「需要」と「供給」という2つの要素が、小売市場における商品の価格を決定づける。

価格 can construct many longer compound words, such as 希望小売価格, 市場価格, 価格調査. I can't think of similar compounds which contain 値段.